# PowerMock whenNew does not return Mocked Object

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I can't get PowerMock `whenNew` to work despite following multiple different resources. Here is my example:

```
public class MyClass {
  public void foo() {
    Point p = new Point(2, 3);
    System.out.println(p);
  }
}
```

I am trying to mock the constructor to `Point` to like so:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
public class MyClassTest {
  public void testFoo() {
    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Point.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(new Point(0, 0));
    c.foo() // Still (2, 3) is printed instead of the mocked (0, 0)
  }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? I should mention that I am using PowerMock in a gradle project. This seems to be identical to https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-new-object-creation-powermock/, so I am not sure why is it not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
        //Arrange
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        Point point = new Point(0,0);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Point.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(point);

        //Act
        c.foo();

        //Assert
        PowerMockito.verifyNew(Point.class).withArguments(anyInt(), anyInt());
    }
}
```

Usually I would return a mocked object. Replace Point point = new Point(0,0) to Point point = PowerMockito.mock(Point.class)